# Why isn't the while-loop working in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop

[I tried a basic while-loop in Python 3.8 but I always get a syntax error. Anybody know why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Die1.png)

I tried Notepad++ but when I write the loop, Python doesn't run

Comment: Please post your actual code, not a screenshot of your code

Comment: The line after needs to be indented, so it's _inside_ the while loop. Any loop or conditional in python needs the line after it (and any other lines 'inside' it) to be indented one level further.

Comment: Notepad++ is a text editor. What do you mean you "tried" it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i = 1
while i <= 5:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

This works in PyCharm, looking at the image it seems that you wrote the if statement
and the print() on the same line. Which also gave me an error.